# Expression evaluation - why parenthesis changes "this" reference?

Tags: javascript

Consider the example module creation, why parenthesis changes `this` reference?

As [section 11.2.2 in JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) says:

> The production NewExpression : new NewExpression is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating NewExpression.
> 2. Let constructor be GetValue(ref).
> 3. If Type(constructor) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 4. If constructor does not implement the `[[Construct]]`
>      internal method, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 5. Return the result of
>      calling the `[[Construct]]` internal method on constructor, providing no
>      arguments (that is, an empty list of arguments).

After some investigation there are no differences (are there?) between:

```
console.log(new (modules.getModule('foo')).method)
console.log(new (modules.getModule('foo')).method())
```

In both samples `method` were executed.

To be more interesting:

```
console.log(typeof new modules.getModule('foo').method) // function
console.log(typeof new (modules.getModule('foo')).method) // object
```

What is the source of those differences?

```js
var modules = (function() {
    var definitions = {
        foo: {
            method: function() {
                this.thing = 'baz';
            }
        }
    };
    
    return {
        getModule: function(name) {
            if(name in definitions) {
                return definitions[name];
            }
        }
    };
}());


alert('this: ' + new modules.getModule('foo').method()) // undefined
alert('this: ' + new (modules.getModule('foo')).method()) // {this.thing = 'baz'}
```

Comment: I don't know all the technical reasons behind it, but if it were `new modules.foo.method()`  instead of `new modules.getModule('foo').method()` , it wouldn't return undefined. It has to do with how Javascript determines what object to pass to be used as the `this` variable. `new (modules.getModule('foo').method)()` would also work. BTW I wasn't able to reproduce your typeof example.

Comment: Mine typeof shows both as function

Comment: @ShekharPankaj - I've missed new operator in second example when checking typeof ; / - updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses don't change the `this` reference of a method call. Parentheses change the `NewExpression` that `new` evaluates.

If the `new` operator is in front of a property chain (an expression followed by accessors), it will evaluate the chain and instantiate the resulting constructor function.

If the `new` operator is in front of a call expression (an expression, possibly including accessors, followed by an arguments list), the call will provide the arguments for the `new` operation. Any trailing accessors will access properties of the newly instantiated object.

For your examples, that means

```
 new  modules.getModule ('foo') .method
 new  modules.getModule ('foo') .method()
// are evaluated as
(new (modules.getModule)('foo'))…
// on which then .method is accessed or called

new  (modules.getModule('foo')).method
new  (modules.getModule('foo')).method ()
// are evaluated as
new ((     …                  ).method)() // the empty parentheses are optional for `new`

(modules.getModule('foo')).method
// just evaluates to the `method` function
(modules.getModule('foo').method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable modules gets the value that is returned by the anonymous function: an object with a method getModule.

In the first case:

```
console.log(new (modules.getModule('foo')).method)
```

*new* is applied to the function *method* of object *foo* (which is the result of *modules.getModule('foo')*. The console should show the *function method*.
In the second case:

```
console.log(new (modules.getModule('foo')).method())
```

Now, *new* is applied to the object *foo* (which is the result of *modules.getModule('foo')*. The object *foo* has a method *method*.
But this time, method is executed. The console should show an object with property *baz*.

```
console.log(typeof new modules.getModule('foo').method) // function
```

Here, you ask the type of the method *method* of the object *foo* (the result of *modules.getModule('foo')*).
The type is, obviously, a function.

```
console.log(typeof (modules.getModule('foo')).method) // object
```

Here, you ask for the type of the method *method* which is part of the object *foo* (which is the result of *modules.getModule('foo')*)

Comment: No, `new` is not applied to the result of `modules.getModule('foo')` (which would be an object, not "*a `foo` function*" - there is no such function)