# Reflect.construct vs new ( object type here )

Tags: javascript, typescript

After using ES6's Reflect.construct, I noticed that parameterizing the object type to new keyword also works.

https://jsfiddle.net/mnw349o5/

```
function Nice() {
    return Date;
}


window.alert(new (Nice())); // will show the date today

window.alert(Reflect.construct(Nice(), [])); // same as above

window.alert(new Nice()); // not the intended
```

Should I still use the approach of passing the object type as a parameter on new keyword to create dynamic object since it seems to also work? Not using Reflect.construct would be one less node module dependency for the project.

Currently I'm using harmony-reflect to polyfill Reflect so I can use it on ES5-targeting TypeScript project.

Comment: I don't get what advantage you see in using `Reflect.construct`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parameterizing"?

Comment: @Bergi re "parameterizing" I don't know how ```new open parenthesis object type close parenthesis``` idiom is called. It's only in javascript I found out that dynamically creating an object with ```new``` keyword is possible. Whereas in C#, I would have to use Activator.CreateInstance, which is analogous to Reflect.construct.

Comment: @Bergi Me too, I don't know what is the advantage of Reflect.construct over newing a dynamic type. But I've use it first, and then I just found out later that newing a dynamic type also works. Hence I'm curious if Reflect.construct has any advantage or disadvantage over newing a dynamic type

Comment: You could say "parenthesize", or "to wrap in paren(thesi)s" or "use the grouping operator". It has nothing to do with parameters.

Comment: You found the disadvantages already: it requires ES6 (or a polyfill). It also is longer (more to type) and won't be understood by the many people not familiar with `Reflect`. There are no advantages in your use case.

Comment: For your specific problem with the parenthesis, see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29966824/1048572) or [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22new+require%22+%5Bjs%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use `Reflect` until you need it (which, in the case of `construct`, would be for setting the newtarget to arbitrary values). You don't need it, so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: hey bergi, do you know of any, or come across any real use cases for reflect?

Comment: @jamesemanon The `Reflect` object contains the default operations for all `Proxy` handlers